# Trying to marshal C++ pointer to unsigned long into a C# ulong

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I have a C++ DLL that I am trying to interface with using C#. I do not have access to the DLL source code so it cannot be changed. One of the methods I need to call contains a pointer to an unsigned long:

```
int __stdcall Foo(FooHandle messageHandle, unsigned long* tag, char* part, char* value)
```

I have created a test DLL project with the same method signature so I can try to figure this out but I have not successfully been able to have the DLL change the value of the unsigned long that the pointer is referencing and get that value back on the C# side. The C# side declaration is:

```
[DllImport("Foo.dll", EntryPoint = "Foo", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern int Foo(int messageHandle, IntPtr tag, StringBuilder part, StringBuilder value);
```

When I make the call from C# and then try to convert the IntPtr to Int32 or Int64 I get a zero. I have searched on here and the net in general as well as MSDN and can't seem to find an explaination of how to do this. I figured the char* would be the hard part but the StringBuilder just works.

How can you use a C++ DLL that changes the value of an unsigned long that is passed by pointer?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the UIntPtr structure: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uintptr(v=VS.100).aspx can provide some help here?

Comment: You did not post how you get the value of the signed value of tag.  I am going to guess that code is wrong.  Of course your signature isn't even the same, tag is a unsigned long reference based on your C++ signature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use a uint passed by ref:

```
public static extern int Foo(int messageHandle, ref uint tag, StringBuilder part, StringBuilder value);
```

Comment: Thank you David, it works! It seems so simple now, I just couldn't put my finger on it.

Comment: can you help with this,      
long  T_main(long Ref_Toc , unsigned long *Input_Toc, long Input_Toc_count,char *Sdf_Path, char Positive_Matching, int Channel_Option, unsigned int *Output_Tocs, unsigned char *Error_Value)

Comment: @Aravind Not in response to a hastily written comment to an answer to another question